# Pytorch CUDA out of memory. Обучение RNN сети

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch, cuda, nvidia

Я написал по уроку RNN-модель (код ниже) , но при увеличении данных для обучения столкнулся с ошибкой: [image: ошибка]

Как мне решить эту проблему и продолжить обучение? Я пробовал уменьшить `batch_size` , писать `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`, уменьшал количество `hidden` слоев - ничего не помогает. Может можно как-то вручную дать больше памяти? *Спасибо за любой ответ.*

**Видеокарта:**

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660

**Код** *(+ text.txt - данные на которых НН обучается; text_2.txt - возникает ошибка)***:**

- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BpGowyXouf-PFn1XLsC3lJj_TjFreRiB?usp=sharing

Comment: У вас же там прям на картинке написано, какой параметр нужно выставить в какое значение. И описание ситуации вроде вам подходит. И не прикладывайте текст картинкой, если его можно скопировать. Прикладывайте к вопросу текст ошибки в виде текста. Так всем проще будет.